# How to prove with identities: $(A - B) \cup (B - C) = (A \cup (B - C)) - (B \cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove with identities that: 
$(A - B) \cup (B - C) = (A \cup (B - C)) - (B \cap C)$
both ways?

Comment: To show that two sets $X,Y$ are equal, we need to show that $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$. You will do each of these cases separately from one another. As a getting started step, you want to take $x \in (A - B)\cup (B - C)$ and show that using definition of set minus and set union/intersection that $x$ appears in $(A\cup (B - C))-(B\cap C)$.

Comment: The trick that i'm asking is to use only with identities without any x ∈....
This is a different question than the other one, you can click the link to see.

Comment: If you permit a universe and change set subtraction to intersection with the (latter) complement it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean $$ A-B = A\setminus B = A\cap B'$$

Then we have:

$$(A\setminus B)\cup(B \setminus C) = (A\cap B' ) \cup(B \cap C')$$

$$=(A\cup(B\cap C'))\cap (B'\cup(B\cap C'))$$

$$=(A \cup(B \setminus C))\cap(B' \cup C')$$

$$=(A \cup(B \setminus C))\cap(B \cap C)'$$

$$=(A \cup(B \setminus C))\setminus (B \cap C)$$

---

I've used Demorgan's theorem:

$$A'\cup B' = (A\cap B)'$$

And distributive law:

$$A\cup(B\cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$$

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.